# Getting error as ZeroGty: Windows DLL failed to load. while running installer to install Mapper Application.( Window 11)

Tags: windows

1.When I run installer in administrator mode to install Mapper application, the progress bar goes up to 100% while installing and after that nothing comes on screen.
2.When I run installer without administrator mode, getting error as
ZeroGty: Windows DLL failed to load
at ZeroGak.b(DashoA10*..)

Expecting to get installed.